# Can not log out in rails with devise due to invalid authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm stuck on this weird problem, which somehow I have never experienced before; and somehow I cannot find anything anywhere on how to solve it.

So my problem is this: When I'm logging out with this link

```
link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

It crashes the application with this message

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#destroy
```

The only other thing I have found here was that this says that someone has already logged out. However, this happens when I have not tried logging out before, nor has the time expired for the user to be logged in.

Is there anyone able to help me?

Comment: Do you have an `after_sign_out_path_for` method in your `application_controller`? I wonder if somehow you've arranged for a double sign out.

Comment: No I haven't, and I don't think it's a double sign out either. Because it doesn't sign out at all :(

Comment: Ok, grasping at straws, but... if you change it to `link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete if current_user` is the link still showing?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm now showing it through `-if user_signed_in?` , `=link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete if current_user`

Comment: And you still have `=csrf_meta_tag` in your application.html.haml ?

Comment: It's possible to bypass token authenticity for the destroy method, but that would be a kludge.

Comment: Oh wow.... I somehow removed `=csrf_meta_tag`, how is it possible I didn't notice?... such a noob error :D THX, file it as answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error indicates that the test for cross site request forgery is failing, because of an expired or missing csrf token.

It's worth checking that your layouts/application.html has the `=csrf_meta_tag` or `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` as appropriate.